# Create Empty Share point Project in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, elevated-privileges

I want to create a Share point web part using Share point 2013. I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Community. But I couldn't create empty share point project in
Visual Studio 2013 Community.

Can I create an empty Share point project Using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate?

Comment: What kind of webpart ? App WebPart or Visual WebPart ? You try to create a Sharepoint Solution or App ? Anyway a Sharepoint Solution require Sharepoint installation on the same machine of Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi @Max I created a webpart not visual webpart.I created a sharepoint solution.I have installed Sharepoint 2013 on the same machine of visual studio.